# Running different sql queries from html button press

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been going crazy trying to figure out how to query a php database upon different buttons the user may press. For example clicking on one button will query the database to return values where age > 30, while clicking on a different button will send a different query so age < 30.

I know that you cannot run a php function directly from a button onclick, however you can run javascript. I have been trying to use javascript that is called from the button to run php queries but its very messy (and isn't working).

I don't have any experience with ajax which may apparently be a solution, but would much rather avoid it.

I don't have to use buttons, I just need a way for the users to choose different queries.

How could I do it?

Comment: php database? Now I've seen everything!

Comment: I don't think i have ever been so confused in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see it is using Ajax.
I would say use [JQUery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it is very very easy to use & learn and you will find a lots of examples here on how to do whatever is it that you want to do. It is the most straight forward solution.

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this is far more helpful than the other comments I have received.